# TabLayout scrolls to unkown position after calling notifyDataSetChanged on PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have sample project with `TabLayout` and `PagerAdapter`.
Strange things happens with TabLayout when I call `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

TabLayout is scrolling to unknown x position so the current tab is not visible. However if I scroll to left to expecting tab, this tab has indicator.

What is going on? Could anyone help me? I have spent on it too many time.

[image]

Below the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        final SampleFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I tested on nexus emulators and nexus real devices (api 21+)

Gradle settings:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.myapplication4"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Link to reported issue and ready to test project as attachment [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=267098)

Comment: Can you post that project?

Comment: click on blue link `here` - the last paragraph of my post

Comment: The error comes from [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#L1190) line: had there not been `- (getWidth() / 2)` it would work as expected. You can test that placing a breakpoint before returning from method and changing `scrollBase` value to a correct one. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-RuirxZUD8).

Comment: Nice one, can I somehow hack it?

Comment: I tried to do via reflection, but there are no enough seams to do that. Nevertheless, that `-width` had some reasoning, which means you'll break something else by changing it. I guess there should be some if-else statement.

Comment: Yes, I see. Imho reflections are not safe for production apps. I will look around this part of code. Maybe there is any other valid solution for that problem. Thanks.

Comment: Place your xml code here please

Comment: How does it relate to xml? All information is in my question.

Comment: @deadfish Please check my answer

Comment: upvoted but I will be able check this tommorow

Comment: @deadfish No issue, test it and let me know if I skipped anything.

Answer (score 8):

Every time setup view pager with the use of `setupWithViewPager` might be costly. Because `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your ViewPager Adapter causing TabLayout to redraw its all views. So for redrawing, `TabLayout` remove all its associated `Views` and re add them.

Please check below thread execution steps which happen after `notifyDataSetChanged` on pager adapter.

```
  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.removeAllTabs(TabLayout.java:654)
  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:904)
  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$PagerAdapterObserver.onChanged(TabLayout.java:2211)
  at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
  - locked <0x129f> (a java.util.ArrayList)
  at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:287)
  at com.sample.testtablayout.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
```

According to thread execution -

Clicked on Action Button > Pager Adapter Notified for data set changed > TabLayout got notification of data change through observers > It try to populate new data from adapter > Removed all tabs.

Below is a code of `TabLayout` class, from which you can check whenever all tabs are going to remove then last selected tab is lost(Intentionally marked null).

```
/**
 * Remove all tabs from the action bar and deselect the current tab.
 */
public void removeAllTabs() {
    // Remove all the views
    for (int i = mTabStrip.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        removeTabViewAt(i);
    }

    for (final Iterator<Tab> i = mTabs.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        final Tab tab = i.next();
        i.remove();
        tab.reset();
        sTabPool.release(tab);
    }

    mSelectedTab = null; // Thats a cause for your issue.
}
```

To retain last selected tab I have created my own CustomTabLayout class and retained last selected position.

```
public class RetainableTabLayout extends TabLayout {

   /*
   * Variable to store invalid position.
   */
   private static final int INVALID_TAB_POS = -1;

   /*
   * Variable to store last selected position, init it with invalid tab position.
   */
   private int mLastSelectedTabPosition = INVALID_TAB_POS;

   public RetainableTabLayout(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public RetainableTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public RetainableTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

   @Override
    public void removeAllTabs() {
       // Retain last selected position before removing all tabs
       mLastSelectedTabPosition = getSelectedTabPosition();
       super.removeAllTabs();
   }

   @Override
   public int getSelectedTabPosition() {
       // Override selected tab position to return your last selected tab position
       final int selectedTabPositionAtParent = super.getSelectedTabPosition();
       return selectedTabPositionAtParent == INVALID_TAB_POS ? 
              mLastSelectedTabPosition : selectedTabPositionAtParent;
   }
}
```

At the end make sure to reselect your tab after recreation of your `TabLayout`.

```
findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // At the end make sure to reselect your last item.
            new Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(
                                 tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
                            if (selectedTab != null) {
                                selectedTab.select();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 100);
        }
    });
```

This issue will resolve your problem but what I believe is `TabLayout` must have to retain last selected position in case of data set change. This is what I understand, any comments or more understanding is welcome.

Comment: After .notifyDataSetChanged no need to create new Handler() and set delay. TabLayout contains Handler. Use tabLayout.post()

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can call:

```
setupWithViewPager(@Nullable final ViewPager viewPager, boolean autoRefresh)
```

and set param `autoRefresh` to `false`.

See also: [`TabLayout(ViewPager,boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager,%20boolean))

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: This solution works perfectly if you have a TabLayout with a custom viewPager with fragments. I needed to update the fragment UI but it crashed in onTabSelected because it redrawed tabs content. I spent literally about 3 hours to achieve this.

Comment: Isn't resetting viewPager is costly in terms of memory management? That's a reason of notifyDataSetChanged() to came in picture.

Answer (score 1):

I just added notifyDataSetChanged method inside of TabLayout implementation of Rasi.

It works for me.

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

/*
   * Variable to store invalid position.
   */
private static final int INVALID_TAB_POS = -1;

/*
* Variable to store last selected position, init it with invalid tab position.
*/
private int mLastSelectedTabPosition = INVALID_TAB_POS;

public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void removeAllTabs() {
    // Retain last selected position before removing all tabs
    mLastSelectedTabPosition = getSelectedTabPosition();
    super.removeAllTabs();
}

@Override
public int getSelectedTabPosition() {
    // Override selected tab position to return your last selected tab position
    final int selectedTabPositionAtParent = super.getSelectedTabPosition();
    return selectedTabPositionAtParent == INVALID_TAB_POS ?
            mLastSelectedTabPosition : selectedTabPositionAtParent;
}

public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = getTabAt(getSelectedTabPosition());
            if (selectedTab != null) {
                selectedTab.select();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

and to notify call

```
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mCustomTabLayout.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This appears to be a cleaner version of Rahul's existing answer, above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436472/1617737

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set the current postion.

you can get the selected position before notifying dataset change and save it in static varaible and update it everytime:

```
public static tabPostion;

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      tabPostion = tab.getPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

//set the postion of the pervious tab
    yourviewpager.setCurrentItem(tabPostion);
```

below is the code from my project :

```
   @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        // imageHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        onClearOrSelectAllImage(FlickQuickEnum.PIC_SELECTION_ACTION.CLEAR);
        selectedImageUrls = new HashMap<>();
        String tag = tab.getText().toString();
        String tagName = tag.substring(1, tag.length());
        currentTab = tagName;
        if (tagName != null) {
            dbAlbumPhotoList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (tagName.equals("All")) {
                dbAlbumPhotoList = dbAlbumPhotosHashMap.get(album.getAlbumName());
            } else {
                dbAlbumPhotoList = dbAlbumPhotosHashMap.get(tagName);
            }
        }
        updatePhotoCount();
        setPhotosSelectedActions(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
```

Comment: yes this code is from my project and it works properly

Comment: I am aslo refreshing the UI of the tabs on some actions but i am not using notifydatasetchange, instead i am using Eventbus to refresh the whole data and UI as per my need

Comment: @deadfish I have used this code in my app and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue, you need modify the TabLayout source code

```
void populateFromPagerAdapter() {
    removeAllTabs();

    if (mPagerAdapter != null) {
        final int adapterCount = mPagerAdapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
            addTab(newTab().setText(mPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)), false);
        }

        // need call post to run the code, to fix children views not layout
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Make sure we reflect the currently set ViewPager item
                if (mViewPager != null && adapterCount > 0) {
                    final int curItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                    if (curItem != getSelectedTabPosition() && curItem < getTabCount()) {
                        selectTab(getTabAt(curItem));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can use the library [link](https://github.com/flztsj/ExtTabLayout)